# WARNING: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-admin

I recently start to have the following warning initiating firebase from a job running on pc.

> WARNING: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute
>   Engine. java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect

Here the Kotlin code that setups firebase:

```
val serviceAccount = FileInputStream("./config/certificate.json")
val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)

val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .setDatabaseUrl(firebaseUrl)
            .setFirestoreOptions(FirestoreOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
                    .build())
            .build()
```

How to avoid this warnings?

Answer (score 1):

By updating `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin` dependency to version 6.9.0 caused the warning to changed Info message level.

> INFO: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.